# Isomorphism between homology groups if we throw away some submanifold from the interior

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Suppose $M$ is a compact manifold with boundary and $D$ is a compact surface with boundary such that$\partial D\subset \partial M$. Why is the map $H_1(M\setminus D)\rightarrow H_1(M)$ an isomorphism when the codimension of $D$ is 3 or more? If the codimension is 2, is the result false? Is there any reference for this kind of statement ?

Comment: For the case of manifolds without boundary, following the maps of Alexander's duality and the cohomology exact sequence of $(M,D)$ gives that the map is an isomorphism whenever $H^{n-2}(D)=0=H^{n-1}(D)$, establishing the result. For the case of manifolds with boundary I'm not sure, but maybe there is some way to adapt the case with no boundary. (For instance, excising some neighbourhood of the boundary and using the condition that $\partial D \subset \partial M$.) If you think it may be useful, I can make an answer elaborating the  case of no boundary.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo, thanks, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This answer considers only the case $\partial M= \emptyset$.**

First off, notice that taking $D$ as the north and south pole of $M=S^2$ gives an example for the result failing in the case of codimension $2$.

Now, proceeding to a proof: we have an isomorphism $H_1(M \backslash D) \to H^{n-1}(M,D)$ due to Poincaré-Alexander-Lefschetz duality.

The exact sequence in cohomology for the pair $(M,D)$ yields
$$\cdots \to H^{n-2}(D) \to H^{n-1}(M,D) \to H^{n-1}(M) \to H^{n-1}(D) \to \cdots $$
It follows that if $H^{n-2}(D)=0$ and $H^{n-1}(D)=0$, then $H^{n-1}(M,D) \to H^{n-1}(M)$ is an isomorphism. Here it is worth noticing that this is the case when $D$ has codimension $3$ or more, since then $n-2>\dim D$. Now, following back through the duality isomorphism $H^{n-1}(M) \to H_1(M)$, we have the composition
$$H_1(M \backslash D) \to H^{n-1}(M,D) \to H^{n-1}(M) \to H_1(M).$$
It suffices  now to see that the diagram
$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} H^{n-1}(M,D) & \xrightarrow{} & H^{n-1}(M)\\
\uparrow & & \downarrow & \\
H_1(M \backslash D) & \xrightarrow{} & H_1(M) \end{array}$$
commutes, where the path $up \rightarrow right \rightarrow down$ is the aforementioned chain of isomorphisms, and the map on the bottom is the map you mention in your post. But this follows from the definition of the duality map and the fact that the top and bottom arrows are the ones induced by inclusions.

Comment: I didn’t get how you got the first isomorphism. I tried, but only obtain $H^1(M\setminus D)\cong H_{n-1}(M,D)$. Which duality theorem are you using here exactly?

Comment: I think if we have higher codimension, these result can be generalized to higher homology, right ?

Comment: @H-H For an explicit and exact reference, you can see Theorem 8.3 in Bredon's Topology and Geometry. It is obtained by capping with an orientation class in Cech cohomology. (Here in this answer, the map is the inverse of the isomorphism there.) And yes, if the codimension is higher, the result can be generalized *mutatis mutandis*.

Comment: @Aloizo Macedo, It is very helpful. This theorem seems more general than those stated in Hatcher's book:  If $L\subset K\subset M $ are compact subsets, then $H^p(K,L)\cong H_{n-p}(M-L,M-K)$.  But I found corollary 8.4 there directly gives what I want: Let $K=M$, above becomes $H^p(M,L)\cong H_{n-p}(M-L)$, then let $L=D$ will give the result. BTW, does compact or closed matter here ?